# How does the browser load content of the previous page?

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm creating a web page with laravel and the main menu pages contents are loaded with ajax. The problem is when I go back to the previous page with the back button of the browser, the browser loads not only the content received by the ajax call but the entire page. So I get two headers and two footers.

This is my code:

base.blade.php:

```
<html>
<body>
```

// list of menu
...

```
<div class="main">
@yield('main')
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

page.blade.php:
    @extends('base')

```
@section('main')
<div class="main">
My page content.
</div>
    @stop
```

// user clicks on the menu link and calls this script
script.js:

```
$(".menu_list").on("click", "a.menu_page", function(e) {
// get some variables
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: url,
dataType: "html",
success: function (result) {
// get only div.main content from result
var mainContent = $(result).find("div.main").html();
// and load this data
$("div.main").html(mainContent);
} ...
```

I also tried not to return the full page data but only the main section in the controller:

controller.php:

```
...
if(Request::ajax()) {
return view('page')->renderSections()['main']; }
```

And in script.js:

```
success: function (result) {
$("div.main").html(result);
```

but it did not have any effect.

So I don't understand why the browser loads the entire page into the @yield section after returning to the previous page, although the controller only returned part of the page content.

Comment: how does `$(result).find("div.main")` work? The rendered result if the request is AJAX would not contain that selector

Comment: In the first example "result" consists data of whole page: menu,main content and footer. And the .find function take off only the div.main part and returns to the page.

Comment: But this script works well, my problem is when I return to the previous page.

Comment: has anyone here ever had this problem?